# How to copy an imbued facet from a stringstream?

Tags: copy, locale, stringstream

Assuming I have imbued a facet in a stringstream:

```
std::stringstream msgStream;
{
   bpt::time_facet * afacet = new bpt::time_facet("%Y-%m-%d\t%H:%M:%S\t0.%f");
   msgStream.imbue(std::locale(msgStream.getloc(),afacet));
}
// How to access the facet in order to copy it?
```

How can I copy this facet from `msgStream` in order to imbue a new copy in another stringstream?
Is there a way to retrieve the facet pointer later if `afacet` goes out of scope but `msgStream` does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're imbuing a `std::locale`, not a `bpt::time_facet`.

You can access the current locale of the `std::stringstream` from `msgStream.getloc()`

With the `std::locale` object, you can access the facet with it's member `facet`:

```
std::locale myLocale = msgStream.getloc();
myLocale.facet; //Operate on the facet. Returns std::locale::facet.
```

You can then cast it to your `bpt::time_facet` if required.

For more info see class references - [imbue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/imbue/), [facet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/facet/), [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/), [locale](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/locale/)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I checked, it works the way I wanted.